# What is the relationship between the TLS version (1.x) and the cipher suite

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I'm writing a client server application that requires a secured connection.

I want to understand better the difference between the TLS version (1.x) and the cipher suites that is in use.

this is the result of an nmap scan on my server (scanned for supported TLS options):

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - D
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (secp256k1) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - D
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (secp256k1) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - D
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (secp256k1) - C
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256k1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256k1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: D
```

What does it mean that a cipher suite is supported in more than one version of TLS?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. They don't devise a whole new set of cipher suites for every protocol revision.

Comment: I still don't understand:
Let's take the first cipher suite for example: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
(that is shown in all versions of TLS in the nmap output above).

By supporting this cipher suite in my server, does my client use TLS 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2?

Comment: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA can be used with SSL 3.0 and higher, i.e. TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2. Which means that just be looking at the cipher suite you don't know which protocol version is used.

Comment: By supporting this cipher suite the server is supporting this cipher suite. You said yourself it's present in multiple TLS versions. Cipher suites and TLS versions are largely orthogonal, except when they imtroduce new suites in new versions.